# How do I tell a Garmin 430 not to exit a hold?

Tags: navigation, avionics, instrument-procedures, gnss, gns430

[image: RNAV 25 KOEB]

Let's say that we're directly west of `CATLI` and have been cleared direct `CATLI` for the RNAV approach.  We load the approach into the GNS430 and proceed direct the fix.

After crossing `CATLI` outbound for the hold-in-lieu-of-procedure-turn, we realize that we want to stay in the hold for a few more turns.  **How do I tell the 430 that I don't want it to sequence to `ZAMGI` upon arrival at `CATLI`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press the OBS button to put waypoint sequencing into suspend, as indicated by the green "SUSP" appearing over the OBS button.

Comment: Knew it was something simple.

Comment: Yep. The OBS button acts as suspend button: 
-in holds 
-on the leg between FAF and MAP
-if on the "from" side of the leg to the IAF, if vectors-to-final is activated.